# Hook midway through the_content();?

Tags: the-content

Basically, I want to add a function that executes half way through the_content();

I want to add a message/ad block whatever in the middle of all of my content without having to go in to each individual page and add the block.

Is this even possible?

Comment: You could count the str length, then output the first part, your ad and then the last part. Btw: It's "Ad", not "Add" :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this function `ad_content()` in replace of `the_content()` in your template.

```
function ad_content() {
$content = apply_filters ( 'the_content', get_the_content () );
$content = explode ( "</p>", $content );
$half_way = ( count($content) / 2);
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $content ); $i ++ ) {
        if ( $i == $half_way ) {
            echo 'YOUR_AD_CODE';

        }
        echo $content[$i] . "</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Function the_content() does not only apply the filters. It also applies `str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content)`. Using a replacement function implies to always check the source of the_content() after a new version of WP is published.

Comment: Thanks for the code - this would replace the entire the_content function? Not sure if I want to go down that road, in case of future changes. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible, you'll just want to write a function that finds the middle of the content then ads your block. Something like this

```
function wpse_37015(){

//get the content   
$content= get_the_content(); //get the content as a variable

// find the middle
$content_length= STRLEN($content);
$halfway_mark = ($content_length/ 2);

// clip off the first half
$firsthalf = SUBSTR($content, 0, $halfway_mark);

// find the last '<br>' in the first half
$end_mark = STRRPOS($firsthalf, '<br>');

// add in the adblob at the position found above

return SUBSTR($content, 0, $end_mark) . "<p> YOUR AD HERE p>" . SUBSTR($content, $end_mark); 
}

add_filter('the_content', 'wpse_37015');
```

This is totally untested and may need to be reworked I got the code to find the middle from [here.](http://psoug.org/snippet/Insert_Into_Middle_Of_Text_144.htm)

**Edit:** As OneTrickPoney pointed out we need to check for HTML tags one method may be to use php's [strip_tags() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) . and add something like this after the first content call:

```
$content = strip_tags($content) //remove html tags
```

the problem will be adding the tags back at the end.

Comment: Yes, you need to find out if you're within a HTML tag, and move the position outside of it.

Comment: This looks awesome - thanks. One Trick Pony - any idea how I would go about doing that? The content is using <p> tags.

Comment: Been playing with this a bit - it doesn't seem to be inserting into the middle of the text. "YOUR AD HERE" is the first paragraph within the content. Any ideas? Thanks guys.